# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1.

I have a model called `Message`, then I wrote a customer class `HttpMailer::Message` located in `lib/http_mailer/message.rb`.

But after this, every place I refer to my model `Message` as a constant I will receive an exception `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Message`. To fix it, I have to move `http_mailer` folder (contains `message.rb` which defines `HttpMailer::Message`) into `app/models`. But I think it should stay in `lib`

Why is that? Where have I done wrong? Or I just should put `http_mailer/messsage` inside `models`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you intend Message to be a model, in the since that Rails defines models, then it belongs in `app/models`. What makes you think that it belongs in `lib`?

Comment: @sealocal Yes `Message` is a model, it belongs to `models` folder. What I mean is `HttpMailer::Message` is a utility class, not a model so I believe it should goes into `lib`, or anywhere else but not `models` right?